# Unable to login to magento admin panel from any browser

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, database, login

I am using magento 1.9
When I try to login to magento with user name and password the page refresh and nothing happen.
facing this issue when i moved my site from siteground to bluehost.
I seen the logs and found that a same error is comming all time.

```
2017-10-10T10:49:30+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70)  in /home4/bedshee9/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 513
```

I have tried every single thing on internet but nothing work. Facing this issue from long time.

Please help.

Comment: did you clear cache ?

Comment: Have you tried private browser window,did you flushed cache?

Comment: @ghdarvishani yes i have done that.

Comment: @kunj yes tried that too.!

Comment: Go to app/etc/local.xml and change the value of **`<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>`** to **`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`**

Answer (score 1):

`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session::read($sessId)` needs to always return string, for example changing
`return $data;` to `return (string)$data;` fix db session handler, login works.

When called on `session_regenerate_id(true)` it returns false which breaks regeneration. It seems it's going to be easy fix.

Comment: can you please help me step by step i am a beginner in magento.

Comment: Walk into class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session` and search method `read` and in him line `return $data;` and replace her `return (string)$data;`